# Laplace Transforms Property

Tags: laplace-transform

Please see image. I'm confused by how the went about to get d[exp(-st)] in the second line

Thanks
[Laplace Transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzLa8.png)

Comment: This is just integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

For $s$ held constant,

$$ e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t = -\frac{1}{s} \,\mathrm{d}(e^{-st}). $$